# Pandas Unable to find file on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pandas

```
# _*_ coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd
import sys

print ''
print 'Pandas Version: ',pd.__version__
print 'Python Version: ',sys.version
print ''

path = 'C:\\Users\\StretchChannel\\Documents\\'
InputFile = path+'test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(InputFile)
```

Output is:

```
Pandas Version:  0.19.2
Python Version:  2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 19 2016, 13:29:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(InputFile)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 389, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 373, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:4184)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 667, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:8449)
IOError: File C:\Users\StretchChannel\Documents\test.csv does not exist
>Exit code: 1
```

Comment: Try to write the path with '\\' `path = 'C:\\Users\\StretchChannel\\Documents\\'`

Comment: No, that does not work....tried that. Note: the IO Error gives the correct path and number of backslashes...it's a real puzzle...

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to  my question: I had renamed test.xlsx to test.csv...Windows 10 "official" name for this file is now: test.xlsx.csv

Unfortunately, this double dotted file name is hidden from view when looking at the directory. In fact, it's shown as test.xlsx

I found the file's real name by clicking on the file's Properties--> Security. The filename is shown at the top of the window.

Lesson: If Pandas (or Python) cannot find the file, look at the file's properties for it's Windows 10 name.

Thanks to all who looked at the question...